# defining a range of values in a while loop

Tags: range

I want to set the while condition to only accept values between 0 and 20? 
when I use >20 only, It works but I don't want any values less than 0.

```
T1 = int(raw_input("Please enter  score  out of 20: "))
while T1!=(0<T1<20):
        print("out of range. Please try again!")
        T1 = int(raw_input("Please enter  score out of 20: "))
else:
    name_array.append(int(T1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if its >= 1 && <=20 So it could check if its in between 1-20.